# Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'

Tags: android, nativescript

i create a nativescript project from scratch --ng, dont add any code and build android; send me this error:
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.

> unable to create new native thread

i add and remove platforms, uninstall full nativescript and install...
pls help me

Comment: i have the same issue. don't u solved yet?

Comment: I chance my hard drive for a ssd and the problem is solved